# How to do popup images from my database inside a table

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

[I code everything on php, so my HTML code is inside an echo]

So I connected to my database and I want to show on my website the data, and everything is fine except for the profile picture (PatientImage)

Firstly I create my SQL command line to select all the columns from my database

```
$sqlSelectP = "select * from tbl_patient";
$QResultSP = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $sqlSelectP);
```

Then I build the table, first the head with the names of the columns

```
//Build Table
echo'
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>FName</td>
            <td>LName</td>
            <td>Roomno</td>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td>address1</td>
            <td>address2</td>
            <td>Postal Code</td>
            <td>Grade Classification</td>
            <td>Image</td> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Then I do the body of my table and it is fine except for my column Image

```
    <tbody>';
while (($Row = $QResultSP->fetch_assoc())) 
{
echo '
         <tr>
            <td>'.$Row['FName'].'</td>
            <td>'.$Row['LName'].'</td>
            <td>'.$Row['Roomno'].'</td>
            <td>'.$Row['Password'].'</td>
            <td>'.$Row['address1'].'</td>
            <td>'.$Row['address2'].'</td>
            <td>'.$Row['PostalCode'].'</td>
            <td>'.$Row['GradeClassification'].'</td>
```

So in the column Image, I will show an icon that is, in fact, a button for a popup window where I want to show the picture of the person. (I used the code from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp)

But on my website, every icon on every line will act as a button for a popup window on the first row only

UPDATE : Now I don't have any popup window (even if I can see that I can click on every icon)

```
            <td> 
                <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(myPopup'.$i.')">
                    <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>
                    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup'.$i.'">
                        <img src="'.$Row['PatientImage'].'.png" alt="'. $Row['FName'].' - Profile Picture" width = "50%" height = "auto">
                    </span>
                </div>
                <script>
                // When the user clicks on div, open the popup
                function myFunction(popupId) 
                {
                var popup = document.getElementById(popupId);
                popup.classList.toggle("show");
                }
                </script>
            </td> 
        </tr>';

}
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Comment: `id's` have to be unique. You are using `id="myPopup"` for every row, so the function will always use the first one it finds.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! It's because an HTML `id` must be unique, when you try to select an element by id, only the first will come up if there are multiple ones. You have to increment a count and use it in your id, as well as in the javascript too (it can be the parameter of the function for example, then no need to re-declare the function for each row, which will cause problems too)

Comment: Regarding this: "[I code everything on php, so my html code is inside an echo]" - I'd advise you to change this behaviour. You can jump in and out of PHP many times within a file. `<?php $foo = 'bar'; ?><div><span><?php echo $foo; ?></span></div>` is a perfectly acceptable way of doing things, it preserves HTML syntax highlighting (assuming your editor supports this), and it means it's much easier to do inline JavaScript (As you can use both `"` and `'` without escaping them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question with your help. I used the method mentionned by sathya seelan, and reworked the function with the idea of Michel.
So I get :

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(\'myPopup'.$i.'\')">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>
    <span class="popuptext_hidden" id="myPopup'.$i.'">
        <img src="'.$Row['PatientImage'].'.png" alt="'. $Row['FName'].' - Profile Picture" width = "50%" height = "auto">
    </span>
</div>

<script>
    // When the user clicks on div, open the popup
    function myFunction(id){
        var popup = document.getElementById(id);
        console.log(popup);
        if(popup.classList.contains('show'))  {
            popup.classList.remove('show');
            popup.classList.add('popuptext_hidden');
        } else {
            popup.classList.remove('popuptext_hidden');
            popup.classList.add('show');
        }
    }
</script>
```

This way I have a unique id for each Picture, and the function is rewritten so that when I click on the icon, the popup window will appear, and then it will disappear if we reclick on the icon

Answer (score 0):

As you create your rows, you need to have the id of the span containing the popup be unique for each of the rows. Make sure it is also the same id that you pass to the function as a parameter. e.g. like below

```
<td> 
    <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(myUniquePopupIdForThisImage)">
        <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>
        <span class="popuptext" id="myUniquePopupIdForThisImage">
            <img src="'.$Row['PatientImage'].'.png" alt="'. 
            $Row['FName'].' - Profile Picture" width = "50%" height = "auto">
        </span>
    </div>
<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction(popupId){
    var popup = document.getElementById(popupId);
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I tried to do as you said and modified my code (I copied your version of myFunction). But I still have the same problem. Here is my code modified:
 
`<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction('.$Row['ID'].')">
 <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>
 <span class="popuptext" id="'.$Row['ID'].'">`

Comment: How does your function now look like?

Comment: In fact I did an error and didn't implement your correction on the good table, now the popup window doesn't appear anymore, I will update my question

Answer (score 0):

```
while(($Row = $QResultSP->fetch_assoc())){
...
...
echo '<td>
    <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(\"myPopup'.$i.'\")">
        <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>
        <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup'.$i.'">
            <img src="'.$Row['PatientImage'].'.png" alt="'.$Row['FName'].' - Profile Picture" width="50%" height="auto">
        </span>
    </div>
</td>';
...
...
$i++;
}
```

At the end of the page put this script

```
<script>
function myFunction(id) {
    var popup = document.getElementById(id);
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>
```

Try this

Comment: This will reduce the number of lines

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible without any id's at all, using `event`:

**html**

```
//add EVENT to the onclick
//use popuptext_hidden as classname
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(event)">
  <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>
  <span class="popuptext_hidden">
     <img src="hello.png" alt="hello.jpg" width = "50%" height = "auto">
  </span>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.popuptext_hidden {  display: none }
.popuptext_show {  display: block }
```

The function wil use `event` to target the button and the image:

**javascript**

**EDIT** Edited so onclick turns on and off. Also now turns off other popups.

```
function myFunction(event){

  //get the div that is clicked
  var button=event.target;

  //the span is the second child from the div 
  //(but the counting starts at 0, so it will be 1)
  var span=button.children[1];

   //toggle the span classname between show and hidden
  if (span.className === 'popuptext_show') {
    span.className = 'popuptext_hidden'
  } else {
    span.className = 'popuptext_show';
  }


// ** TURN OF ALL THE OTHER POPUPS THAT ARE OPEN
// so only one popup is open at any time
// (leave this out if you don't need it)

   //get list of all popups that are on
  var list = document.querySelectorAll('span.popuptext_show');
  for (var i=0, len=list.length; i<len; i++) {
    //leave the current span alone
    if(list[i]===span)continue;
    //turn off the rest
    list[i].className = 'popuptext_hidden'
  }


}
```

[Here is a little fiddle to show how it works](http://jsfiddle.net/kNB3c/4176/)

Comment: This method work yes, but is there a way to hid again the popup window ? Like a kind of reverse function ?

Comment: Updated script and fiddle

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, but now when I implemented your function, it doesn't do anything when I click on the icon. 
But when I put `<span class"="popuptext"` instead of `<span class="popuptext_hidden"` I will first see the icon and the image side by side at first, but the first time I click on the icon, the popup will appear with the image inside, making the image next to the icon disappear. But it only work once. Do you know where the error may come from ?

Comment: Did you change the css to `.popuptext_show` and `.popuptext_hidden`? And the class of the `<span>` as well?

Comment: I changed the css and when I change the class of the `span` nothing happen at all when I click onto the icon

Comment: Well, as the Fiddle works, you must be doing something wrong. Put an `alert()` inside the function, to see if it pops up. Then check in the console if the class is changing when you click.

Comment: I have this error in the console : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined
    at myFunction (showTable.php:614)
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (showTable.php:73)`

Comment: Ah, then `<span>` isn't the second child. Try this instead: `var span = button.querySelector('span[class^="popuptext_"]');`
`

Comment: I tried your change, I put `var span = button.querySelector('span[class^="popuptext_"]');`  instead of `var span=button.children[1];` But I stil have the same error 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null`